# Why do I get charged more than the depositary fees + withheld taxes on my American Depositary Receipt (ADR)?

Tags: united-states, stocks, dividends, fees, adr

I have `894` shares of [AXAHY](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AXAHY) (which is an [American depositary receipts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_depositary_receipt) (ADR)) on my Fidelity brokerage account. According to [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/128226/5656) by [Flux](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/20480/flux), the depositary fees for AXAHY in 2020 are `0.04` USD per ADR. Therefore, my depositary fees for 2020 should be `894 * 0.04 = 35.76 USD`. However,
I got charged a `40.23` USD fee. What could explain this discrepancy? Am I getting charged something else other than the depositary fees?

Note that the `40.23` USD fee doesn't include the taxes withheld by the ADR company's local government (which is in this case the French government, who withholds [12.8%](https://invest.bnpparibas.com/en/taxation-dividends#:%7E:text=Dividends%20paid%20to%20individuals%20who,non-cooperative%20state%20or%20territory.) of the AXAHY dividends, which matches the "foreign tax paid" row on my Fidelity brokerage account and which I don't mind as the AXAHY shares are placed in a taxable account, so I can claim tax credits via [IRS Form 1116](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1116)).

I contacted Fidelity's customer service and they have no clue.

---

Interestingly, my [Merrill Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merrill_Edge) brokerage account, which also contains some ADRs, is much clearer regarding ADR fees:

1. It clearly states "Depository Bank (ADR) Fee" on the history of operations.
2. It distinguishes the dividend fee (`0.04/ADR/year` for AXAHY, as confirmed by [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/128258/5656) by [Flux](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/20480/flux)) from the tax relief fee (`0.005/ADR/year` for AXAHY, as confirmed by [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/128258/5656) by [Flux](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/20480/flux)). However both are labeled "Depository Bank (ADR) Fee".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I getting charged something else other than the depositary fees?

The discrepancy is caused by a "Tax Relief Fee" of $0.005 per share:

[image: AXAHY 2020 cash dividend]

<sub>Source: [AXAHY 2020 Cash Dividend Announcement](https://www.adrbnymellon.com/publicSiteProxyExport.jsp?resourceName=getExportDsf&statusCode=F&cactnId=170000052884&exportFormat=pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200728005229/https://www.adrbnymellon.com/publicSiteProxyExport.jsp?resourceName=getExportDsf&statusCode=F&cactnId=170000052884&exportFormat=pdf))</sub>

So the fees you paid are:

- `894 * 0.04 = 35.76`
- `894 * 0.005 = 4.47`

Total: `35.76 + 4.47 = 40.23`

If not mistaken, the "Tax Relief Fee" is an administrative fee charged by the depositary bank to minimize your taxes (e.g. by taking advantage of tax treaties). I've asked a follow-up question about this "Tax Relief Fee" ([What are "Tax Relief Fees" on American Depositary Receipt (ADR) dividends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/128260)), because I too would like to know for sure.

Comment: This is extremely interesting, thanks a lot for digging that out and for asking the other question!

Comment: Follow-up question: [Is there any upside in owning American depositary receipts (ADR)) instead of owning the underlying stock directly, if that's possible?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/128311/5656)